# Unexpected results in subtraction of double in function

Tags: c++, function, arguments, double, subtraction

I'm trying to implement the eigenfaces algorithm in C++. I already made the database creation part and now I'm setting up the recognition part.

The only problem is that even if all the variables are correctly read from the file `"prova.txt"`, once they are passed to the function something odd happens: the whole `imd` array contains values that differ from the expected ones (I've the same algorithm running in Matlab for reference).

I'm a python programmer so I know that probably it's something silly for a C++ user, but I can't find errors in my code (probably not very well optimized and full of redundancies btw). I'm posting a link to the `"prova.txt"` after the code.

`U` and `omega` are matrices, that I linearized in order to be able to pass them as input arguments of the function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int confrontodb(double*, double, double, double*, double*, double*);

int confrontodb(double* test, double H, double M, double* m, double* U,
                double* omega) {
  int Urows = M;
  int Ulines = H;
  double om[Urows];
  double imd[Ulines];
  double d[Urows][Urows];
  double dist[Urows];
  double accum;
  double minimo;
  int ind = 0;

  // subtract average "med" from test sample "test"
  for (int i = 0; i < Ulines; i++) {
    imd[i] = test[i] - m[i];
  }
  // Project "imd" on the U eigenspace (om = U'*imd)
  for (int i = 0; i < Urows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Ulines; j++) {
      om[i] += U[Urows * j + i] * imd[j];
    };
  };

  // Generate a matrix in which each column is a copy of om
  for (int i = 0; i < Urows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Urows; j++) {
      d[i][j] = om[i];
    };
  };

  // subtract omega from d
  for (int i = 0; i < Urows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Urows; j++) {
      d[i][j] = d[i][j] - omega[i * Urows + j];
    };
  };

  // norm each column of d
  for (int i = 0; i < Urows; i++) {
    accum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < Urows; j++) {
      accum += d[i][j] * d[i][j];
    };
    dist[i] = sqrt(accum);
  };

  // look for minimum and maximum distance
  minimo = dist[0];
  double massimo = dist[0];
  for (int i = 0; i < Urows; i++) {
    if (dist[i] < minimo) {
      ind = i;
      minimo = dist[i];
    } else if (dist[i] > massimo) {
      massimo = dist[i];
    };
  };

  cout << "minimo " << minimo << endl;
  cout << "massimo " << massimo << endl;
  return ind;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  ifstream f;
  f.open("prova.txt");
  double* omega;
  omega = (double*)calloc(198 * 198, sizeof(double));
  for (int i = 0; i < 198 * 198; i++) {
    f >> omega[i];
  };
  for (int i = 0; i < 198; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 198; j++) {
      cout << "   " << omega[i * 198 + j];
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  double* U;
  U = (double*)calloc(4001 * 198, sizeof(double));
  // float U[4001*198];

  for (int i = 0; i < 4001 * 198; i++) {
    f >> U[i];
  };

  double* med;
  med = (double*)calloc(4001, sizeof(double));
  for (int i = 0; i < 4001; i++) {
    f >> med[i];
  };

  double* test;
  test = (double*)calloc(4001, sizeof(double));
  for (int i = 0; i < 4001; i++) {
    f >> test[i];
  };

  f.close();
  cout << "etichetta riconosciuta "
       << confrontodb(test, 4001, 198, med, U, omega) << endl;
  free(med);
  free(test);
  free(U);
  free(omega);
  return 0;
}
```

[Link to `"prova.txt"` (it's 13 megabytes)](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=98697908462504898225)

Expected results:

```
imdmatlab = 
  -2.5252525e-01
  -1.3080808e+00
  -1.8080808e+00
  -2.7676768e+00
  -4.1161616e+00
  -3.1969697e+00
  -2.5707071e+00
  -2.6616162e+00
  -3.1616162e+00
  -2.3181818e+00
  -2.1767677e+00
  [...]
```

With the actual code, the first `imd` element is correct, the second has a 1/1000 error and then everything goes randomly, so these elements should be enough to check).

Comment: Did you try to run your code in a debugger and follow values to see when exacly the wrong values are computed?

Comment: Computing sums that way tends to be very inaccurate because towards the end, you're adding a very small number to a much larger number. I'd suggest just using a [better type](http://www.mpfr.org/) than `double`.

Comment: Are the computed value wrong, or just slightly different? Data type `double` is an inpricise type and using different languages or hardware can result is slightly different results.

Comment: some numbers are wrong even on the most significant digit